# How to simplify logs but keep the same base

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider the function: $f(x)=\log_3x+\log_316-\log_34$. This can be simplified to $\log_34x$. To simplify this function in Mathematica, I would use the command

```
Simplify[f[x]]
```

Which would output $\frac{\log4x}{\log3}$. One could argue whether this was more simple than $\log_34x$, but I would prefer for the base not to be changed when simplifying. This would only be applicable when all of the $\log$s in the function are to the same base.

So how can you tell Mathematica to not simplify the base of a logarithim?

Comment: `Log[3, 4]` gets evaluated to `Log[4]/Log[3]` immediately.  This is not done by `Simplify`.  It is an evaluation rule of `Log`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, so would this type of functionality not be possible in Mathematica?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do specifically.  It's more complicated than you assumed.  Try `HoldForm[Log[3,4]]`. It stays as it is, but it cannot be used for computations. It is for display purposes. An end result could be post-processed using `Log[x_]/Log[y_] -> HoldForm@Log[y, x]` to put it back into the form you wanted.  There's also `Inactive`, e.g. `Inactive[Log][3, 4]`.  `Inactive` is usable in *some* computations, but I am not sure it is helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Szabolcs points out in the comments, you can't do this the way you would like because it isn't a display rule but an evaluation rule that causes `Log[x,y]` to turn into `Log[y]/Log[x]`. You can try to edit the display for this expression after the fact but it quickly becomes intractable; to demonstrate, we could overload the `MakeBoxes` function for the fraction form:

```
MakeBoxes[expr : Log[x_]/Log[y_], form_] := MakeBoxes[Log[y, x], form];
Log[x,y]
```

> Log[x,y]

This works, but if we enter something a little more complicated...

```
2*Log[x,y]
```

> 2 Log[y] / Log[x]

This happens because the latter expression gets evaluated into `Times[2, Log[y], Power[Log[x], -1]]` which is then passed to `MakeBoxes`, and this expression doesn't match `MakeBoxes` argument. We could further modify `MakeBoxes`:

```
MakeBoxes[Times[a___, Log[x_], b___, Power[Log[y_], -1], c___], form_] := 
  MakeBoxes[#, form] &@Times[a, HoldForm[Log[y, x]], b, c];
MakeBoxes[Times[a___, Power[Log[y_], -1], b___, Log[x_], c___], form_] := 
  MakeBoxes[#, form] &@Times[a, HoldForm[Log[y, x]], b, c];
10*Log[3,4]/2
```

> 5 Log[3,4]

But even here we get unexpected results when the expression gets a little more complicated:

```
Exp[2 * Log[3, 4]]
```

> 4 ^ (2 / Log[3])

I think this result is preferable to leaving `Log[3,4]` in the exponent, but the point is that you won't be able to control the display of this function very easily.

Another thing that might occur to someone is to overload how Log actually works; something like this:

```
(* This is a bad idea! *)
Unprotect[Log];
Log[x_, y_] =.;
Log /: N[Log[x_, y_]] := N[Log[y]/Log[x]];
```

I doubt that code would work, but even if it did and you could successfully handle all the cases in which `Log` is passed to `N`, you would probably break all sorts of Mathematica internals like `Solve`, `Minimize`, `Simplify`, etc., all of which expect `Log` to simplify itself.